# Error after assigning one instance of a derived type to another instance (Coarray Fortran)

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran, fortran-coarrays

My problem could not be reproduced with simple code. So let me post an overview of the problem, and let's see if this generates a solution or a hint.

I have a complex derived type (say, emulator_sp) that has several components including an allocatable coarray component. I have two instances of the type, I1 and I2. First, I initialize I1, including allocating its coarray component:

```
call init_emulator_sp(I1)
```

and then do some other stuff with I1

```
call do_other_things(I1, ...)
```

This works without a problem. However, if I now assign I2 to I1, this breaks:

```
call init_emulator_sp(I1)
I2=I1
```

check that all components of I2 and I1 are the same on each image

```
call do_other_things(I2, ...)
```

The error pops up:
forrtl: severe (772): Image number 17 is not a valid image number; valid numbers are 1 to 16

Note that the program works on 16 images, and I1 is defined on 16 images.

Compiler information:
ifort (IFORT) 19.0.3.199 20190206
Copyright (C) 1985-2019 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Again, I apologize for not posting a simpler isolated code, since I could not reproduce this error on a simpler example. Nonetheless, does anyone have any pointers?

P. S. This is the type definition, if this helps at all:

```
type emulator_sp
     real, allocatable                        :: pars(:,:,:,:)[:]
     character(128), dimension(3), private    :: state_var_names 
     character(128), dimension(5), private    :: forc_var_names 
     logical                                  optimized
     integer, dimension(2)                    :: train_yrs
     character(10)                            :: parnames(15)
     character(128)                           :: parunits(15)
  end type emulator_sp
```